# PHPUnit: include class after mocking it

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm happily writing unit tests, but they clash when I run them all together. I'm testing this class:

```
class MyClass {

    public function sayHello() {
        return 'Hello world';
    }
}
```

using this test. All tests have a structure like this:

```
class MyClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    private $subject;

    public static function setUpBeforeClass() {
        require_once('path/to/MyClass.php');
    }

    public function setUp() {
        $this->subject = new MyClass();
    }

    public function testSayHello() {
        $this->assertEquals('Hello world', $this->subject->sayHello());
    }
}
```

`MyClassTest` runs fine on its own. But PHPUnit will **crash because I redeclare the class**, if another test mocks `MyClass` and happens to run first:

```
class Inject {

    private $dependency;

    public function __construct(MyClass $myClass) {
        $this->dependency = $myClass;
    }

    public function printGreetings() {
        return $this->dependency->sayHello();
    }
}

class InjectTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testPrintGreetings() {
        $myClassMock = $this
            ->getMockBuilder('MyClass')
            ->setMethods(array('sayHello'))
            ->getMock();
        $myClassMock
            ->expects($this->once())
            ->method('sayHello')
            ->will($this->returnValue(TRUE));

        $subject = new Inject($myClassMock);

        $this->assertEquals('Hello world', $subject->printGreetings());
    }
}
```

I do use a bootstrap.php to fake some global functions not yet refactored.

I have no auto loaders and don't want to process-isolate EVERY test, because it takes forever. I tried inserting combinations `@runTestsInSeparateProcesses` and `@preserveGlobalState enabled`/disabled in the docblocks of both Test 1 & 2, I still get the same error.

Comment: You need to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Why are you setting up your mock via a `require_once` statement rather than using proper mock functionality using Mock Builder API? Read this: https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects

Comment: @hek2mgl, I hope this example is better.

Comment: @MikeBrant, require_once includes the subject under test, not the mock (which is built using the API). I've updated the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To understand this behaviour, you need to have a look at how PHPUnit works. `getMockBuilder()->getMock()`, dynamically creates the following code for the mock class:

```
class Mock_MyClass_2568ab4c extends MyClass implements PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject
{
    private static $__phpunit_staticInvocationMocker;
    private $__phpunit_invocationMocker;

    public function __clone()
    {
        $this->__phpunit_invocationMocker = clone $this->__phpunit_getInvocationMocker();
    }

    public function sayHello()
    {
        $arguments = array();
        $count     = func_num_args();

        if ($count > 0) {
            $_arguments = func_get_ ... 

     # more lines follow ...
```

If `MyClass` hasn't already been loaded at this time, it adds the following dummy declaration:

```
class MyClass
{
}
```

This code will then getting parsed using `eval()` (!).

Since PHPUnit will execute `InjectTest` **before** `MyClassTest`, this means that the mock builder will define the dummy class and `MyClass` is already defined when `MyClassTest::setUpBeforeClass` will get called. That's why the error. I hope I could explain. Otherwise, dig into PHPUnit's code.

---

**Solution:**

Drop the `setUpBeforeClass()` method and put the `require_once` statement on top of the tests. `setUpBeforeClass()` is not meant for including classes. Refer to the [docs](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/fixtures.html#fixtures.sharing-fixture.examples.DatabaseTest.php).

Btw, having `require_once` on top will work because PHPUnit will include every test file **before** starting the first test.

*tests/MyClassTest.php*

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../src/MyClass.php';

class MyClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    private $subject;

    public function setUp() {
        $this->subject = new MyClass();
    }

    public function testSayHello() {
        $this->assertEquals('Hello world', $this->subject->sayHello());
    }
}
```

*tests/InjectTest.php*

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../src/Inject.php';

class InjectTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testPrintGreetings() {
        $myClassMock = $this
            ->getMockBuilder('MyClass')
            ->setMethods(array('sayHello'))
            ->getMock();
        $myClassMock
            ->expects($this->once())
            ->method('sayHello')
            ->will($this->returnValue(TRUE));

        $subject = new Inject($myClassMock);

        $this->assertEquals(TRUE, $subject->printGreetings());
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your explication of the `dummy` declaration helped a lot. I assume all php test files are included before the first test is executed?

Comment: @PeerBr Oh yes, all php test files are included before the first test is executed, that's why the dummy class declaration will not happen then (as require_once on top of MyClassTest had already been executed). This is important, missed to say that...