# PHPUnit using required_once

Tags: php, phpunit, require

I have a scenario that I wanted to 'derequire' or just the `require_once` needs to be on that class only.

I learned that in PHPUnit the test files are gonna be included. And because of that, the required_once is overriding the class that I needed. I needed to use the original class. Is it possible?

[PHPUnit: include class after mocking it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25693038/3409596)