# phpunit issues instantiating new class for testing - "error loading class file" for unrelated classes

Tags: php, phpunit, instantiation

I'm trying to test my message class, but when I run phpunit I get three errors in the console:

```
1) messageClassTest::testCanBeCreatedFromMessageIDAndFBMPageAccessToken
error loading class file: /Users/ads/org/repo/classes/PHPUnit/DbUnit/TestCase.php
error loading class file: /Users/ads/org/repo/classes/Symfony/Component/Yaml/Yaml.php
error loading class file: /Users/ads/org/repo/classes/Composer/Autoload/ClassLoader.php
Undefined index: fallback

/Users/ads/org/repo/classes/message.php:47
/Users/ads/org/repo/classes/message.php:170
/Users/ads/org/repo/ci_tests/messageClassTest.php:18
```

The error exists when I instantiate the Message class, which is completely unrelated to the classes in the error log, and it works perfectly in the class file when I instantiate it the same way there.. what am I doing wrong?

Also, the other three errors below pointing to the message class file are non-fatal errors about an empty value not present in an array, so I don't think my trouble is there.

Here is my unit test file:

```
<?php

// backward compatibility
if (!class_exists('\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase') &&
    class_exists('\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase')) {
    class_alias('\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase', 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase');
}

require_once __DIR__ . '/../classes/message.php';


class messageClassTest extends PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase {

    private $message;

    public function setup() {
        $FBM_PAT = "token";
        $this->message = Message::createNewMessage(1, $FBM_PAT);

    }

    public function testCanBeCreatedFromMessageIDAndFBMPageAccessToken()
    {

        $class = Message::class;
        $message = $this->message;
        $this->assertInstanceOf($class, $message);
    }
}




?>
```

Also, I instantiated the message object in the way suggested by this other Stack Overflow post:

[PHPUnit: include class after mocking it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693038/phpunit-include-class-after-mocking-it)

Comment: are you using symfony ? version ?

Comment: I am not using symphony. However, I solved my problem. Refer to the answer below if you were curious!

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question - I guess the undefined index was not a fatal error for testing the actual class in it's own file, but it was a fatal error for phpunit. I just added a conditional check for if the fallback value exists, in the class file, and it fixed my problem... :D